# PHP using "Temporary" databases

Tags: php, database, json, laravel

i'm working on a small script to "call people in comming order" from a big hall. To be more specific (its a little hard to explain it on my non-foreign lang), the people come at this building, take a number and wait to be called from a big monitor, displaying the page on full-screen mode.

So, i have two "routes" (or scripts), a "Monitor" that show the main windows with the actual number and the terminal that is calling, this is for the big monitor on the hall. The second one its a "Controls" that have some controls like "Number +". "Number -", etc.

The comunication with this two scripts is with jquery and json data.

So.. there are more than one "Controls" windows, a variety of machines that can "call" for a number.

The "Controls" scripts, saves the data on some Databases. And the Monitor script, checks for new data every 1s and change the number and the terminal calling with jquery for the new one.

For that reason, i have to store the data on a Database. i have MySQL on a shared server here but i prefer to store the data local in the server machine, without depend on a server.

What is the best option for that? the first come to my mind is .TXT databases, but its an ugly solution. What about store the data on a Json files? SQLite its not an option.

Plus, the database will be reseted every day.

Im working with Laravel (if its matters), maybe Laravel offers some solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use APC, Alternative PHP Cache:

http://php.net/apc

Comment: Great! not for the "APC" but for using Cache for that, Laravel comes with caching backends like Memcached and Redis out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You might check small database (SDB) language . It is written in php and uses json. See It here:http://pagenotes.com/wordpress/2011/12/08/sdb/

Answer (score 0):

Just use WAMPserver...

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Provided youre on windows

Then you just 'host' your site, locally

Comment: No. MySQL and MySQLite are not and option

Comment: Is there a reason?  Isnt that what youre using now?

Comment: because this is part of a more big plataform writen with laravel. The reazon i dont want to use the database server (MySQL) is that i want to keep it "clean" and without a query every second

Comment: Well you need that, youre building a 'data intensive' app....you need a database...whats the problem with writing every second....I use laravel too.....laravel makes working with database models extremely easy....I dont see the problem, infact, its the 'cleanest' solution really